# Algebraic closure of p-adic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I want to show that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ has infinite degree. I did a similar problem on quadratic extension, we used Hensel's Lemma. But here it seems there is no such a polynomial to choose. How should I start this problem?

Comment: For a rather extreme way to do this, google for Konrad's notes on the Artin-Schreier theorem.

Comment: @Watson The link you put in the comment is exactly this page.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750131) is related, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675114), also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^n-p$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q_p$ by Eistenstein, so $[\Bbb Q_p(\sqrt[n]{p}):\Bbb Q_p]=n$. Thus $[\Bbb Q_p^{alg}:\Bbb Q_p] \geq [\Bbb Q_p(\sqrt[n]{p}):\Bbb Q_p] = n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You could try showing that if you let $\zeta_m$ be a $p^m$-th root of unity, then $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_m)$ has degree $\varphi(p^m)=p^{m-1}(p-1)$ over $\Bbb Q_p$. Then, if the algebraic closure $\Bbb Q_p^{\mathrm{alg}}$ has finite degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q_p$, you could take $m$ with $p^{m}>n$ to obtain inclusions $\Bbb Q_p\subseteq \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_{m+1})\subseteq\Bbb Q_p^{\mathrm{alg}}$, which gives a contradiction by looking at the degrees over $\Bbb Q_p$.